# Drupal - Counting data in nodes, creating custom statistics

Tags: drupal-6, statistics, nodes

I'm building some custom content types to capture customer data on a website. Admins will enter the data, users will be able to view it, but I also need to be able to bolt on some statistics and infographics to the data.

The problem I have is that I can't see any simple way of doing this within Drupal. Are there modules which can produce simple stats on selected node types or will I have to write a complete custom module using the [data abstraction layer?](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/database/6)

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah turns out if you want truly custom stats then the simplest thing is to build whatever you need in PHP using the data abstraction layer.

Plug into the DB via Drupal and do whatever you need to do...